# android prompt user to enable location services intent error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-intent, android-gps

I have an app that needs to use location services for one of its features. So when the user clicks on a button, I would like my app to check to see whether the device has location services enabled, and if it doesn't prompt the user to enable it via an AlertDialog. When the user clicks the 'Enable Location Services' button, I want the app to take the user to the settings page where the user can enable it.

> My problem is that when the user clicks the 'Enable Location Services'
>   button, instead of opening up the settings page, the app goes straight
>   into the main activity.
>
> **Note**: This is all happening inside of a fragment whose parent activity is my second Activity. So here is the layout of my app: **MainActivity** (login page) => **Second Activity** (parent activity) => **fragment** (where this check must occur).

Here is my code inside of the fragment's onCreateView method:

```
            currentLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                DataActivity dataActivity = (DataActivity) getActivity();
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!dataActivity.isLocationServiceEnabled()){
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("To use this feature, you must first enable location services");

                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Enable Location Services", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
                            }});

                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }});
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS Enabled...");
                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

> **Note**: currentLoc is an imageView that is created inside the
>   fragment_layout file

More information:

- compileSdkVersion 26
- buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
- minSdkVersion 14
- targetSdkVersion 26
- compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
- compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26+'

I have tried countless variations that all use intents and for **this** project they all take me back to the login page (MainActivity). When I create a new project and use the same code, it works...

Comment: As per the new Location service API, you can prompt the user for the permission with a dialog box without taking them to the settings. As the user selects Yes, the location service is enabled. So the user need not go to settings.

Comment: This link may help in implementing location settings dialog. This is the location settings dialog which lets you turn your locations settings ON or OFF directly from here without leaving from your own app to the devices settings. [New Google location service](http://www.androidrey.com/android-location-settings-dialog-tutorial/)

Comment: Do I need to add a dependency or something, because android studio doesn't recognize the GoogleAPIClient. The following import doesn't work: import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient; - android is red and Android Studio says: "cannot resolve symbol 'android'" for all imports of the same sort.

Comment: Yes you will need to add below line to your build.gradle's dependencies: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'

Comment: I just tried that and it worked. Now one final question. How can I modify it so that I can use it inside of my fragment. Perhaps create a separate class that does this and create an instance of the request class? There won't be an onCreate (all the code will be in the class's constructor?) Any advice to get me started would be appreciated. Otherwise I followed the tutorial in a separate android studio project.

Comment: I created a method inside my DataActivity (parent activity of the fragment) called isLocationEnabled(). In it I pasted the code from the onCreate method of the example. I added the implements in the DataActivity class definition and implemented the methods just like in the example. In my fragment I did DataActivity dataActivity = (DataActivity) getActivity(); and then when the user clicks on the button: dataActivity.isLocationEnabled(); But I am still getting the same error. No dialog appears and I am taken back to the login page (the main activity screen)

Comment: Make your method static and call it from your fragment. As the control comes in onActivityResult, check for the current fragment instance using instance of and from there pass your data to your fragment. This can be one of the approach.